# Access Raspberry PI Django server from outside

Tags: django, networking, raspberry-pi, portforwarding

I have a Raspberry PI with Django installed. The PI has a static IP on my network (`192.168.1.100`) and the web server is on port 8008.

I can access my website from the local network at the address `http://192.168.1.100:8008/` as one would expect.

On my routeur, with WAN address (say) `1.1.1.1`, I forwarded port 8008 to the IP `192.168.1.100` and therefore I should expect `http://1.1.1.1:8008/` to show me my website. However it doesn't.

When I redirect port 8008 to another PC where I have an Apache server on port 8008, it works fine from the outside. I only have the problem on this device.

The Django app itself does not seem to reject connections from the outside (I installed it on my Mac on a different network and I could access it from the outside).

So I don't know what I am missing... is there some parameter on the PI that could block requests?

Comment: What does your router logs say?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg nothing shows up in the log. The router is a TP-Link TL-WR543G by the way.

Comment: If it doesn't show your website, what does it show?

Comment: @dutt I get a connection timeout

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution. You can try services like [localtunnel](https://localtunnel.me) or [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to port forward.

Or if you want a more rigid solution you could forward ports from your router.

Or at last you could use a reverse proxy from cloud or a VPN network.

Choose whatever suits your situation the best.

Answer (score -1):

In settings.py, try adding your WAN address to allowed hosts